# How to do global search in Angularjs from json array?

Tags: angularjs, search

Iam able to display and filter search results in the same view..But how can i create search box in header navbar which is common to all pages. On click of search button should open the separate page and should load the search results alphabetically from json array based on the value entered in search box. How to do this? Kindly help

Comment: I think we may need a bit of extra information here.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried.. You can just say do this..

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of attacking your problem. If i understood your problem correctly you wanted to filter out a JSON array...

So lets say in mainCtrl we have this:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/Users'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.usersJson = response;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.error("Something Happened...");
  });
```

So lets say that data above gives us a sample of Users that look like this:

```
"Username" : {
"name" : "Username",
"value" : "Hello World"
}
```

Then in our html if we want to go through the data:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="search" />
  <p ng-repeat="message in messages | filter: search">
    Name: {{ message.name }}
    Message : {{message.value}}
  </p>
</body>
```

You have to learn more about the ngFilter Directive and Filtering in AngularJS In general.. [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter) is the docs about it.. Hope this helped!

**EDIT**

If you want to do this in multiple controllers, just make a service to serve as a communication beetween controllers...

```
app.service("jsonArray", function($scope){
  this.getArray = function(){
   $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/Users'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        return response;
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.error("Something Happened...");
      });
   }
})
```

Now you can inject this service to a controller and simply do jsonArray.get() to get the JSON List..

How to inject service into controller?

Sample:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ["$scope", "jsonArray", function($scope, jsonArray){

}])
```

Hope this helped..

Comment: It works if both input and the results in same view with same controller. But if search box is common to all pages. And search results in different page with different controller. On click of search button, I vl open the search results page. So can you plz help to link between these controllers

Comment: Edited the anwser so it adressed the problem your having now @User1

Comment: Service method is not set up properly to return anything